# ProgrammingError at /tasks/ (1146, "Table 'database.tasks_task_parent_task' doesn't exist")

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, relationship

I'm trying to join a table to itself using many-to-many. I keep getting an error that the table does not exist
Model

```
class Task(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 description = models.TextField()
 percentage_of_realization = models.IntegerField()
 parent_task = models.ManyToManyField("Task", default=None)
```

Migration:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Task',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('title', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('description', models.TextField()),
            ('percentage_of_realization', models.IntegerField()),
            ('parent_task', models.ManyToManyField(default=None, to='tasks.task')),   
        ],
    )
```

I tried to write tasks in different ways like without "" or like tasks.task and modify with migrations, but nothing worked

Comment: You apparently did not make migrations/migrate the database.

Comment: Problem it that I did

Comment: Try doing that in two migrations. In first create a table and then add field. You can also do that in one migration, but in two steps using `migrations.AddField`

Comment: That wasn't working too IT was in first version

Answer (score 0):

Try using "self" instead of "Task":

```
class Task(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     description = models.TextField()
     percentage_of_realization = models.IntegerField()
     parent_task = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="child_tasks", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```